# how i can access to parent control form from user control in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

i have a from with a panel that i add user control to pabel in C# winform.
i wont clear control from main form panel and add new usercontrol to panel from into added user control.
thanck for your help.

Comment: You can use `this.Parent` But what do you want to know about the parent? Usually the parent should know about your `UserControl`.

Comment: Use events to communicate from a control to a parent.

Comment: thancks Reza Aghaei